# How to prompt first paragraph after every image

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to prompt every paragraph after every image in an active document. For some reason, the prompt pops up empty.

```
Sub Example1()
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim strCaption As String

'loop through inline shapes
For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count
'check if the current shape is an picture
    If ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Item(i).Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then
       strCaption = Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range
       MsgBox strCaption
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range` isn't defined by your code.

Comment: @Variatus It’s defined inside the “IF” or what should I change?

Comment: `Selection` is the range which is currently selected in the document. It's a UI thing. Addressing an InlineShape doesn't by VBA `Select` its range on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code might work, depending upon how your InlineShapes are positioned. The code presumes that each picture is in its own paragraph and then picks out the next.

```
Sub Example1()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strCaption As String
    Dim Rng As Range

    With ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        'loop through inline shapes
        For i = 1 To .Count
            With .Item(i)
                'check if the current shape is a picture
                If .Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then
                    Set Rng = .Range.Paragraphs(1).Range
                    With Rng
                        Do
                            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                            .MoveEnd wdParagraph
                        Loop While Len(Trim(.Text)) = 1 And _
                                   .End < .Document.Content.End
                        strCaption = Rng.Text
                   End With
                   MsgBox strCaption
                End If
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It works perfectly thank you. I have another issue, is there a way to loop through the paragraphs to check if the paragraph is empty until it finds text and stores it into the string variable?...I am new to vba

Comment: I have modified the code to ignore blank paragraphs except for the last one in the document. In fact, if the last paragraph in the document contains the picture itself, an error will occur.

Answer (score 0):

If the text you're after is in the same paragraph as the inlineshape you could use code like:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim iSHp As InlineShape, Rng As Range
For Each iSHp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
  Set Rng = iSHp.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range
  With Rng
    .Start = iSHp.Range.End
    MsgBox .Text
  End With
Next
End Sub
```

If the text you're after is in the next paragraph after the inlineshape you could use code like:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim iSHp As InlineShape, Rng As Range
For Each iSHp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
  Set Rng = iSHp.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range
  With Rng
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .MoveEnd wdParagraph, 1
    MsgBox .Text
  End With
Next
End Sub
```